# Scheduled Events in .NET Console App?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a function that I would like to  have called every day at 11:59 PM. The console application will be running 24/7.

My first thought was to  have a timer run every minutes and check if it is 11 59 PM, but I am wondering if .Net has a better way.

Thanks

Comment: The only way to do this would be to use a timer as far as I know. Unless you change your program to be a scheduled process.

Comment: Sounds like a simple way to do it. As long as the app dont crash and exit unexpectedly.

Comment: I would use Quartz.NET.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Console app + Windows scheduled task is the simplest solution.

For a more complex scheduling needs look into [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Windows Service to make this happen automatically. This service should be registered in the services. The windows Service Controller Manager has the timer option to trigger the automatically on particular time.

Comment: @leppie Why does that seem more likely than a 24/7 console app crashing?

Comment: @Servy: With a service you are likely not to notice that it died.

Comment: @leppie The same could be said of a console application.  The service can at least be set to restart automatically.

Comment: @Servy: A service can auto-restart?

Comment: @leppie Yep, I was just going to get a screenshot.  It's the `Recovery` tab of the properties menu.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the snapshot of the task scheduler, create your console application with some arugments, and then add a task there.

[image]